# '.$name.' inside php include won't work

Tags: php

I need some help. I have

```
$siteurl = "http://sitename.com/"; /* Site URL */
```

In my config.php which is included in my header. I can't get this to work

```
<?php include_once(''.$siteurl.'inc/header.inc.php'); ?>
```

Why won't this work?

Comment: Are you trying to include files from another server? Because don't.

Comment: If it's your own site, use a local path, not a URL. If it's not your own site, you probably can't include someone else's header in your site.

Comment: It so the user can enter their site url in config.php and it places it in the include just in case they put their site in a subfolder.

Comment: If you're including a PHP file via URL (even if it's on the same server), then it's probably being executed by the webserver rather than served as raw code. If you want to include a file regardless of where the site is located in the directory structure, use `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` or similar as an anchor.

Answer (score 1):

You have to append physical path of the file to include it.

$siterootpath ="/path/to/root/directory/";
include_once($siterootpath.'inc/header.inc.php');

Please let me know if this helps you. Thanks

Comment: Can I put the $siterootpath in the config.php and still have it work?

Comment: This should be written in config file once and accessed whenever needed.

Comment: So $siterootpath ="/path/to/root/directory/"; will be placed in the config.php and include_once($siterootpath.'inc/header.inc.php'); will be placed in index.php? If that's the case it doesn't work.

Comment: Any help I don't know what to do. ^^

Comment: Nope I have <?php include_once($siterootpath.'inc/header.inc.php'); ?> and in my config.php I have $siterootpath = "/mypath/to/root/directory/";  and it doesn't work.

Comment: What is your root path? "/mypath/to/root/directory/" is this you root path?